# Scala Play 2.5 Filters, Correct way to do them?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am wondering what is the correct way to add custom filters to my play 2.5 project. The play documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters) says to create a Filter class and add it to application.conf.

There seems to be another way by overriding the httpFilters value (with my Sequence of custom filters) that is within BuiltInComponents

Are both of these methods valid?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create classes that extend the `Filter` trait (which will force you to implement an `apply` function), in their example they create a filter that does some logging:

```
class LoggingFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {

  def apply(nextFilter: RequestHeader => Future[Result])
           (requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis

    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>

      val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis
      val requestTime = endTime - startTime

      Logger.info(s"${requestHeader.method} ${requestHeader.uri} took ${requestTime}ms and returned ${result.header.status}")

      result.withHeaders("Request-Time" -> requestTime.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

You can create as many of these as you want.  Then to actually hook these into your requests, you need to create an implementation of the `HttpFilters` trait, where you specify the filters you want to use on each request.  In their example they are using the built-in `GzipFilter` for compressing responses, as well was the `LoggingFilter` they defined earlier:

```
class Filters @Inject() (
  gzip: GzipFilter,
  log: LoggingFilter
) extends DefaultHttpFilters(gzip, log)
```

If you name this class `Filters` and place it in the root level of the app Play will pick it up automatically.  If you want to rename the class, or move it somewhere else, then you will have to add that to you `application.conf` file so that Play knows where to find it:

```
play.http.filters=some.where.MyFilters
```

Comment: In my application, I am extending this trait called BuiltInComponents can I just override the HttpFilters value that exists in BuiltInComponents?

Comment: `BuiltInComponents` is intended for Dependency Injection.  I would stick to the way they recommend in the docs (the same way I outlined in my answer).

Comment: What do you mean intended for Dependency injection? In the docs they use Guice with the @Inject, however in my project I am using Macwire; won't there be a conflict?

Comment: "Play provides a BuiltInComponents trait that allows you to create a pure Scala implementation that wires together your app at compile time".  That is from here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection.

Comment: Yes, and in the BuiltInComponents can't I just override the HttpFilters?

Comment: Maybe you can, is there an advantage in doing that way?  Instead of doing it the way that the Play authors have documented?

Comment: Seems less of a hassle by directly overriding the HttpFilters value. Than creating a class and having it in the application.conf

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you don't need to override the value in the `application.conf` file if you name the class `Filters` and place it in the root of your app.

Answer (score 0):

two ways:

1. custom filter class, then configure that class in the application.conf
2. class called Filters extending `DefaultHttpFilters`, **in the root package**

Don't think there's a correct way, both valid. me personally, I don't like having classes in the root package.